# Combining Wordpress Plugin Functions

Tags: image, wordpress

I'm trying to add some additional information in my image captions. (see example [on my site](http://bitsybride.com/test/)) I found a plugin that adds an extra field to the caption and am trying to augment it to fit my needs.

The plugin is Image Credit and it adds 2 lines in the image uploader - one for the source text and another one for the link. I have another plugin called [Media Tags](http://www.codehooligans.com/projects/wordpress/media-tags/) that allows you to apply tags to images. In the function below, I tied to add the media tags with $mt_terms.

```
add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode', 'wp_image_credit_img_caption_shortcode', 10, 3 );
function wp_image_credit_img_caption_shortcode($attr, $content, $html){
global $post;
$content = (object)$content;
$credit = wp_image_credit_get_credit_link(substr($content->id, strpos($content->id, "_") + 1));
$mt_terms = the_mediatags($post->id);

$result = <<<END
<div id="{$content->id}" class="wp-caption {$content->align}" style="width: {$content->width}px">{$html}</span><p class="wp-caption-text"> {$content->caption} <div style="float: right; width: 50%;"><p class="wp-caption-text"></br>$credit</p></div><div style="float: left; width: 50%;"><p style="font-size:12px"></br> tags: $mt_terms </style></p></div></div>
 END;
return $result;
 }
```

Any advice?

@Filipe
I'm going more this route:

```
 add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode', 'wp_image_credit_img_caption_shortcode', 10, 3 );
 function wp_image_credit_img_caption_shortcode($attr, $content, $html){
global $post;
$content = (object)$content;
$credit = wp_image_credit_get_credit_link(substr($content->id, strpos($content->id, "_") + 1));

$mt_terms = 'Tags: ';
$tags = (array)wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, MEDIA_TAGS_TAXONOMY);
if ($tags) {
    foreach($tags as $tag_item)
        $mt_terms = $mt_terms . ',' . $tag_item->name;
        }
else
    $mt_terms = "postID: $post->ID";

$result = <<<END
<div id="{$content->id}" class="wp-caption {$content->align}" style="width:    {$content->width}px">{$html}</span><p class="wp-caption-text"> {$content->caption} <div   style="float: right; width: 50%;"><p class="wp-caption-text"></br>$credit</p></div><div style="float: left; width: 50%;"><p style="font-size:12px"></br> tags: coming soon! $mt_terms </style></p></div></div>
 END;
return $result;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood what you want, but the best way to add information to a post is using **Custom Fields**, that can be read later with a code similar to this one:

```
get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'MyCustomField1', TRUE );
```

Hope this help.